# Creating a master java script file to use within other javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I wanted to create a master javascript file to handle some common methods like alert boxes, displaying error messages etc. 
 Would it be a good practice to utilize the JQuery .getScript?

Comment: It won't neccessarely be bad practice, but it would be better practice to just include that "master" file in it's own script tag, before the other files using it.

Comment: Or minify all the JavaScript into a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad practice, but if you are looking for best practices I would recommend using the **import statement** (ES2015).

The concept of modules is the best way to separate concerns in your app. Here's the description and an example that I took from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) about the import statement:

> The import statement is used to import functions, objects or
>   primitives that have been exported from an external module, another
>   script, etc.

Example:

```
// --file.js--
function getJSON(url, callback) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () { 
    callback(this.responseText) 
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}

export function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
  getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}

// --main.js--
import { getUsefulContents } from "file.js";
getUsefulContents("http://www.example.com", data => {
  doSomethingUseful(data);
});
```